# How to create an x server with Singularity

Tags: linux, xserver, singularity-container

Overall, I am trying to render images using Unity on a remote cluster.

The cluster does not have an X server; I don't have sudo permissions, or can start a Docker container, but I can start a Singularity container.

My plan is to create a container that would simulate the X Server. I created the following Singularity definition file:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04

%post
    # xvfb for rendering in headless mode
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y xvfb mesa-utils xorg
    echo "allowed_users = anybody" > /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

I started the container with the option  `--containall`. From the container, I launched the command  `/usr/bin/X :0`, but it failed with the following error:

```
Singularity xvfb.sif:~> /usr/bin/X :0
_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-140-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux cooper 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 08 April 2021  01:57:21PM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.9 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/pierre-louis/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed May 26 09:17:05 2021
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/pierre-louis/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Not any `/dev/tty*` exist. Then I tried to launch `startx`, but only to get the same message error.

How can I launch an X Server using a Singularity image?

Comment: `Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)` So _where_ do you want to _show_ the content of the x server? I believe you should research `vnc`.

Comment: Nope I don't want to visualize the content of the x server, I just want to render Unity images in memory, to load them eventually in my PyTorch tensors.

Comment: `visualize the content of the x server, I just want to render Unity images in memory` well, where do you think vnc renders it's "view"? Also, your question does not mention Unity at all. Maybe consider adding more context? Are you asking XY question?

Comment: I actually mentioned Unity. But to provide more context, the final goal is to replicate evaluations from here: https://github.com/alexpashevich/E.T./ which depends on Ai2THOR, which is a research platform for embedded agents that relies on Unity. When used on a Linux server, Unity is using OpenGL, which requires me to use an X Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a separate discussion, `Xvfb` is not supposed to be start through `startx` or `/usr/bin/X` but rather with the supplied run script.